# Jquery datepicker throwing too much recursion error

Tags: jquery-ui, button, datepicker

Im trying to modify the jquery datepicker with done button as clear button. but it is throwing too much recursion error...
my code is,

```
function datePickerToCompareTwoFields(){
    var dformat = document.getElementById('dateFormat').value;
    $( '#popup_container, #popup_container1' ).datepicker({
        beforeShow: customRange,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        closeText: 'Clear',
        dateFormat: dformat,
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        showOtherMonths: true
    });
    $.datepicker._generateHTML_Old = $.datepicker._generateHTML;
    $.datepicker._generateHTML = function(inst) {
        res = this._generateHTML_Old(inst); 
        res = res.replace("_hideDatepicker()","_clearDate('#"+inst.id+"')");
        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please put up an example of the code on jsfiddle or something. I don't know where to start with this.